# Custom MVC Helper ForModel and Dataannotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created a DatePickerFor Helper but it is not getting the validators of my ViewModel.

My viewmodel:

```
public class Dates
{
    public DateTime ExpiringDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required!")]
    [LessThan("ExpiringDate")]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
}
```

My helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DatePickerFor(this HtmlHelper helper,Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression /*, Some args*/)
{
     StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
                html.Append("<div class=\"input-group\">");
                html.Append("<span class=\"input-group-addon\"><i class=\"fa fa-calendar\"></i></span>");
                html.Append("<input id=\"" + id + "\" type=\"text\" name=\"" + name + "\" value=\"" + dateValue + "\" class=\"form-control datepicker " + cssClass + "\" data-dateformat=\"dd/mm/yy\" placeholder=\"00/00/0000\" " + attrs + "/>");
                html.Append("</div>");
     return new MvcHtmlString(html.ToString());
    }
```

Is possible to have "data-val-required" and others validations defined in the viewmodel added to my html?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to override the default TextBoxFor helper and extend the output with your custom properties

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DatePickerFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var extendedAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

        extendedAttributes.Add("class", "form-control datepicker");
        extendedAttributes.Add("data-dateformat", "dd/mm/yy");
        extendedAttributes.Add("placeholder", "00/00/0000");

        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, extendedAttributes);
    }
```